# Is there a way to transform a node OSM point into the reference GPS system of a car?

Tags: openstreetmap, coordinate-system, map-matching

I have a car with a GPS (WGS84) and a camera (who shot the road) fixed on it. I would like to know is there is a way to get the transformation from a OSM node to the GPS Cartesian coordinate fixed on the car ? So that I can get easily project the coordinate of the GPS into the picture (from the camera) coordinate.

I don't know if this is a problem of map matching because I don't want to match a trajectory (like for example https://mapmatching.3scale.net/) but I just want to get the node next to the car and then have the transformation between the two.

Do you have an idea ?

Comment: What coordinate system are you using on your camera/GPS? Nowdays GPS units can do pretty much any common spatial reference - projected or geographic. The question is what tool are you going to use to transform your node? ArcGis, OGR, MapInfo... it *really* isn't the sort of thing that you'd like to do without a library.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my post. This is Cartesian coordinate.Hum actually I don't know, I'm new in this field and I would like to know if we can do that and in which way ? Thanks

Comment: If you haven't already done so download QGIS - one of the best open source (free) GIS packages, it will help a lot. Openstreetmap is Spherical Mercator http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/EPSG:3857, your GPS is probably WGS84 (but that's by no means a certainty)... if you open in QGIS with the Open Layers plugin you can view your data with the OpenStreetMap data, the hardest part is communicating with your camera/GPS (I have no experience there).

Comment: Okey I'll but the visualization is not a problem for me. I used some tools from OSM to visualize the nodes and the way, but now my problem is to get the transformation between two gps coordinate...Not easy.

Comment: No, there's a lot of maths. GDAL/QGIS uses PROJ.4 (https://trac.osgeo.org/proj/) which is open source.. are you coding this or are you trying to get an out of the box solution? If coding, what language (python, C, C++, C#, VB.net, VB6, Java...)?

Comment: I Used c++ as a programming language. I would like to code it in order to use it on my application for some purpose, but if there is already an existing code who works well, I don't mind using it. Useless to invent the wheel again ;). The software you mentioned do that ?
In a big picture, find the nearest node of OSM to match with the GPS signal of my car.

Comment: PROJ.4 is the way to go, QGIS discourages C++ in favour of python. Get the libs (for windows) from http://www.gisinternals.com/ with GDAL (library for reading rasters with georeference) which includes OGR (library for reading/manipulating vector) and PROJ.4 there is a tutorial http://www.gdal.org/ogr_apitut.html get/create the node(s) as OGRGeometry and call TransformTo http://www.gdal.org/classOGRGeometry.html#ae3f0b441fbf2f66ce3ef3571268ab10f - easy as (well, easier than what you've already done). When you have some code please post if/when and where you're having trouble.

Comment: Okey I'll download the package gdal+map server. It contains everything right ? Hum I'm not familiar with Python but I'll try. 
Hope It will be the right way. Keep you posted @MichaelMiles-Stimson ! thanks
But Another question: So just with longitude and latitude, I can project it into the GPS signal of my Car ?

Comment: You don't need mapserver unless you're setting up a web page. Projecting from anything with a spatial reference to any spatial reference is easy, the TransformTo handles it all. You do need to find out what your 'from' and 'to' are but they're usually well defined (like lat/lon is WGS84 and Open Street Map is Spherical Mercator - EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3857).

Comment: Hum I downloaded the package from the website but I don't have any installer and I didn't find a good tutorial to use it.
By reading other GIS post, I saw that everything was included in https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/wiki
Such a pity that I have to use Windows. I'm more familiar with Linux system.
Anyway, Thanks you for your time !

Comment: GDAL/OGR is on linux too, I just don't know anything about it. It doesn't need to be installed, just extracted to a folder and then linked to in your C++ project (include/lib path) the tutorial previously mentioned is sort-of ok, but the best one is in the package with the tools (mostly C though, but it wasn't too difficult to understand). Whether you choose Linux or Windows OGR using PROJ.4 is likely to be the best way. OSGeo4W is also a good installer for GDAL; I use the GISInternals package myself (it comes in 64bit).

Comment: Okey Thanks you for the precision @MichaelMiles-Stimson . I'll try to set up the lib and the bunch of code you provided below. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I would [convert OSM to a shapefile](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Using_OpenStreetMap#Usage_examples), it makes it easier to use and protects against 'black spots'.

Here's a bit of code to get you started:

```
// GDALAllRegister(); // More recent versions don't separate OGR from GDAL
// READ http://www.gdal.org/ogr_apitut.html FOR MORE INFO
char* BasePath = ""; // FILL IN FULL PATH TO SHAPE FILE
OGRRegisterAll();
OGRDataSource *hDS = NULL;
OGRSFDriver   *Driver = NULL;
hDS = OGRSFDriverRegistrar::Open(BasePath,FALSE,&Driver);
OGRLayer *Layer = hDS->GetLayerByName("Polyline");
OGRSpatialReference* LayerSR = Layer->GetSpatialRef();

OGRSpatialReference WGS84 = OGRSpatialReference(0);
WGS84.importFromEPSG(4326);// THIS IS WHERE EPSG: NUMBERS COME IN HANDY

// create a query geometry, YourX, YourY need to be in the same spatial reference
// as the osm data. This limits the features returned to just the ones near the X,Y
OGRPoint pt;
pt.setX(YourX);
pt.setY(YourY); 
pt.assignSpatialReference(LayerSR);
OGRGeometry* QueryGeom = pt.Buffer(SutableDistance); // make a buffer of the point

Layer->SetSpatialFilter(QueryGeom);
// now the layer will only return intersecting features..
Layer->ResetReading(); // initialize
int pCnt = Layer->GetFeatureCount();
if (pCnt > 0)
{
    OGRFeature* pFeat;

    while ((pFeat = Layer->GetNextFeature()) != NULL)
    {
        OGRGeometry* pGeom =  pFeat->GetGeometryRef(); // get the geometry for the feature..
        pGeom->transformTo(&WGS84);// Now the geometry is in WGS84
        // READ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747370/how-to-extract-vertexes-of-geometries-in-esri-shapefiles-using-ogr-library-with
        // ABOUT GETTING THE 'NODES' IN THIS LINE
    }
}
```

After you have broken down the line into vertices it's pythagorean to find the closest vertex. You need to know which way you're headed to decide what the next one is (with the line direction or against it)... to get sensible distances you would need to project both points to a projected coordinate system like UTM, Lamberts or Albers.. the parameters for these depend on where you are but a mathematical formula can decide which parameters is most appropriate.